# 定期支払いのPayPal REST APIを実装する方法を教えてください。

Tags: paypal, rest

PayPal REST APIで定期支払いをどう実装するのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

定期支払いのPayPal REST APIを実装するには、次の4つのステップがあります。
1.  請求設定の作成（Create a plan）
2.  請求設定の有効化（Update a plan(Active a Plan)）
3.  請求処理規約の作成（Create an agreement under a plan）
4.  請求処理規約の実行（excute the agreement）
開始する前に、ご使用の REST APIアプリの設定で、REST APIのアプリ購読（Subscriptions）がオンに切り替えられていることを確認します。

**請求設定の作成：**
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-plan

```
curl -k -v -H 
“Content-Type:application/json” 
-H “Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN” 
-d '{“name”:”Test REST Club Plan”,
“description”:”Template creation.”,
“type”:”fixed”,
“payment_definitions”:[{“name”:”Regular Payments”,
“type”:”REGULAR”,
“frequency”:”MONTH”,
“frequency_interval”:”2”,
“amount”:{“value”:”100”,
“currency”:”USD”},
“cycles”:”12”,
“charge_models”:[{“type”:”SHIPPING”,
“amount”:{“value”:”10”,
“currency”:”USD”}},
{“type”:”TAX”,
“amount”:{“value”:”12”,
“currency”:”USD”}}]}],
“merchant_preferences”:{“setup_fee”:{“value”:”1”,
“currency”:”USD”},
“return_url”:”http://returnurl”,
“cancel_url”:”http://cancelurl”,
“auto_bill_amount”:”YES”,
“initial_fail_amount_action”:”CONTINUE”,
“max_fail_attempts”:”0”}}' https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans
```

PayPalは、「P-」で始まる請求設定IDを返します。

**請求設定の有効化：**
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#update-a-plan

```
curl -k -v -H 
“Content-Type:application/json” 
-H “Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN” 
-d '[{“path”:”/”,
“value”:{“state”:”ACTIVE”},
“op”:”replace”}]' https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/
```

**請求処理規約の作成**
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-an-agreement

```
curl -k -v -H 
“Content-Type:application/json” 
-H “Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN” 
-d '{“name”:”Test REST Club Plan”,
“description”:”Template creation.”,
“start_date”:”2015-03-20T07:49:27-07:00”,
“plan”:{“id”:”PLAN_ID_HERE”},
“payer”:{“payment_method”:”paypal”},
“shipping_address”:{“line1”:”111 First Street”,
“city”:”Saratoga”,
“state”:”CA”,
“postal_code”:”95070”,
“country_code”:”US”}}' https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements
```

PayPalは、以下のように、ECトークンでエクスプレス チェックアウトのリダイレクトURLを返します。
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
顧客を、復帰URL経由でPayPalサイトにリダイレクトする必要があります。請求処理規約が承認されると、顧客は、[請求設定の作成]で設定されたreturn_urlであるお客さまのECサイトにリダイレクトされます。

**請求処理規約の実行**
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-agreement

```
curl -k -v -H 
“Content-Type:application/json” 
-H “Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN” 
-d '{}' https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-TOKEN_HERE/agreement-execute
```

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask